# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack how can i fix it

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, zip

I'm trying to plot in python (2.7), but I'm getting this ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack.

My code looks like this:

```
x, y = zip(*list_with_data) 
xlocs = np.arange(len(x))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.bar(xlocs + 0.6, y)
ax.set_xticks(xlocs + 1)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
ax.set_xlim(0.0, xlocs.max() + 2)

plt.show()
```

My

```
list_with_data = Counter(numbers(text))
```

I want the x-label to be, the numbers that the text includes:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6...

and I want my y-label to represent: how many times they are included in the text.

example:

```
x: 1, y: 150
x: 2, y: 20
```

how can I plot this from my dataset?

Comment: what is list_with_data?

Comment: its a text file with 50k letters.
and I need to count every letter to calculate the probability, then I should use this probability and generate a random text.

Comment: I did it with help from @Padraic Cunningham.
But thanks guys.

Comment: Why do you keep destroying your own posts?

Comment: Because it's useless, it's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are zipping just the keys of the dict keys so you only have one value hence the unpacking error:

```
In [12]: list_with_data = Counter("1 2 3 2 3 4 5 6")

In [13]: zip(*list_with_data)
Out[13]: [(' ', '1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '6')]
```

If you want  to unpack two values you need two values:

```
In [14]: x, y = zip(*list_with_data.items())  
In [15]: x
Out[15]: (' ', '1', '3', '2', '5', '4', '6')

In [16]: y
Out[16]: (7, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: @py.codan, what so you want to plot x as letter and y as frequency?

Comment: should work fine so, an alternative would be `x, y = list_with_data.keys(),list_with_data.values()`